# Displaying pdf on web browser in other formats

Tags: html, pdf, svg, png

It is difficult to have full control over how pdf document is rendered on the web browser (adjusting the zoom, page size, etc.) when it is embedded in an html document. So, I am considering to convert pdf documents in advance into formats such as svg or png, and embed them into an html document instead of embedding a pdf file. A multi-page pdf document will correspond to multiple files of svg or png, which will be stored in a directory. I can handle the change of page according to the user input using JavaScript, and that is not a problem.

1. Given that the pdf documents are scanned documents at around 300dpi, black and white, and the converted file should have a comparable quality, what format would be best suited for this situation mostly in terms of rendering speed on the browser? I understand that cache will change the speed, so I want to limit my consideration to when the pages are rendered for the first time. I have svg or png in mind. Which one is better, or is there a better format that can be easily be converted to from pdf?
2. When a bitmap document such as png is zoomed to a different size, I understand that it will be jaggy. On the other hand, if I feel that, if I have a svg file that embeds such scanned parts, anti-aliasing will work, removing the jagginess. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: *Given that the pdf documents are scanned documents at around 300dpi, black and white* - scanned PDFs generally are merely images embedded in PDFs. A lossless solution not requiring you to render the PDF would be to extract those images and use them as they were embedded, JPEG or other bitmap.

Comment: @mki That is the possibility I mentioned as using png. What do you think about svg compared to that?

Comment: *What do you think about svg compared to that?* - I don't know much about SVG; I would expect it to be more resource-hungry, though, than mere PNG/JPEG (depending on the type of embedded images) extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what format would be best suited for this situation mostly in terms of rendering speed on the browser?

Once it is in the browser, the bitmap (PNG) will be faster. However if the PDF is mostly text and vectors, it will generally be a lot faster to first viewing.  Downloading is usually slower than rendering.

If the PDF just consists of high resolution scans, then the two approaches will be roughly equivalent in terms of speed.

> if I have a svg file that embeds such scanned parts, anti-aliasing will work, removing the jagginess. Is my understanding correct?

No, that is not correct.  A bitmap image does not magically have infinite resolution when put inside an SVG.  If you scale up the SVG, the bitmap inside will still get jaggy.  Same as if it wasn't in an SVG.

Comment: I think anti-aliasing does apply to scanned pictures in svg when the original pixel and the pixel on the browser does not match one-to-one. It is not magic, and it has nothing to do with infinite resolution.

Comment: You may get *interpolation*, but it will still be 'jaggy'.  Interpolation is not the same thing as antialiasing.

Comment: Right. The jagginess due to scanning, which is relevant when the zooming size is greater than the original, cannot be resolved. But the jagginess due to the mismatch of pixel sizes between scanning and display, can be resolved. Perhaps, I used the wrong term; I should have wrote interpolation as you told me.

Comment: Even with interpolation, the jagginess will still be apparent and will get worse the higher you scale it.  The OP gave me the impression that they thought an SVG would be able to scale a bitmap without any jagginess.  It won't. That's what I was responding to.